# Is there a way to launch ec2 template less than 10 sec?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am working on WebRTC audio-video calls where I have installed the required tools (i.e Kurento media server, signaling server, and turn server ) installed in AWS ec2 image and created a launch template from it. I want to launch 1 instance for 1 call but the uptime of the launch template is around 20-30 seconds which is too much.

Is there a way to reduce uptime to less than 10 seconds?

Comment: You start the existing instance, or create new one?

Comment: I am trying to start a new instance from the launch template. I have also tried launching existing stopped instances but it's also taking the same time.

Comment: If you are installing bunch of custom software, clreate a custom AMI and use that in your template.

Comment: yes, I did the same. I created AMI and used it to create a template and that template uptime is 20-30 seconds which I am trying to reduce.

Comment: Than that's it. You can't do anything else. Look at ECS or Lambda.

Comment: Lambda has the limitation of a maximum uptime o 15 minutes per execution and ECS Fargate doesn't allow TCP UDP connections.

Comment: ECS Fargate allows UDP connections if you use a Network Load Balancer

Comment: Your terminology is backwards. You don't start a new instance or launch a stopped instance.

Comment: Regarding Fargate and UDP, see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/aws-fargate-now-supports-udp-load-balancing-with-network-load-balancer/).